# My code is giving me a segmentation fault

Tags: c

In my code I get a segmentation fault every time I try to run it. I have tried to comment out the majority of the code and only leave the initialize function and function call in the code so I believe that the segmentation fault is due to that function. However I do not know how to fix the error after trying for a while. I am including all of the code in case there is something from another function that is causing the fault and I am incorrect.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// function prototypes
void initialize(int* one, int* two, char* ch);
void getHoursRate(double* pRate, double* hrs);
double payCheck(double rate, double hours);
void printCheck(double rate, double hours, double amount);
void funcOne(int* pOne, int pTwo);
void nextChar(char* ch);

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    char z;
    double rate, hours;
    double amount;
    int* one = 0;
    int* two = 0;
    char* ch = NULL;
    double* pRate = 0;
    double* hrs = 0;
    
    // call initialize here...
    initialize(one, two, ch);
    printf("After initialization: x = %d, y = %d, z = %c\n", *one, *two, *ch);

    //call getHoursRate here...
    getHoursRate(pRate, hrs);
    rate = *pRate;
    hours = *hrs;
    //call payCheck here...
    amount = payCheck(rate, hours);
    //call printCheck here...
    printCheck(rate, hours, amount);

    x = 35;
    y = 20;
    printf("Before calling funcOne: x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    //call funcOne with x & y here...
    funcOne(&x, y);
    printf("After funcOne: x = %d\n", *one);
    
    z = 'B';
    printf("Before nextChar z = %c\n", z);
    //nextChar with z here...
    nextChar(ch);
    printf("After nextChar: z = %c\n", *ch);
    
    return 0;
}
void initialize(int* one, int* two, char* ch){
    one = 0;
    two = 0;
    strcpy(ch, "~");
}
void getHoursRate(double* rate, double* hours){
    printf("Enter hours worked: ");
    scanf("%lf", hours);
    printf("Enter pay rate: ");
    scanf("%lf", rate);
    
}
double payCheck(double rate, double hours){
    double amount = 0;
    
    if (hours > 40){
        amount += 40 * rate;
        amount += (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5;
        return amount;
    }
    else{
        amount += 40 * rate;
        return amount;
    }
}
void printCheck(double rate, double hours, double amount){
    printf("Hours worked: %lf\nPay Rate: %lf\nThis week's salary: %lf\n", hours, rate, amount);
}
void funcOne(int* pOne, int pTwo){
    int temp;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    *pOne = (*pOne * 2) + pTwo - temp;
}
void nextChar(char* ch){
    ch++;
}
```

Comment: ***Lot*** of null pointer access in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the way variables are passed by reference, look at this fixed version :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// function prototypes

void initialize(int* one, int* two, char* ch);
void getHoursRate(double* pRate, double* hrs);
double payCheck(double rate, double hours);
void printCheck(double rate, double hours, double amount);
void funcOne(int* pOne, int pTwo);
void nextChar(char* ch);

int main()
{
    int x, y;
    char z;
    double rate, hours;
    double amount;
    int one = 0; // ==== Variable must not be declared as pointers
    int two = 0; // ==== They becomes pointers when you pass them
    char ch = 0; // ==== to the function,
    double pRate = 0;
    double hrs = 0;
    
    // call initialize here...
    initialize(&one, &two, &ch); //<======= FIX HERE
    printf("After initialization: x = %d, y = %d, z = %c\n", one, two, ch);

    //call getHoursRate here...
    getHoursRate(&pRate, &hrs); //<======= FIX HERE
    rate = pRate;
    hours = hrs;
    //call payCheck here...
    amount = payCheck(rate, hours);
    //call printCheck here...
    printCheck(rate, hours, amount);
   
    x = 35;
    y = 20;
    printf("Before calling funcOne: x = %d, y = %d\n", x, y);
    //call funcOne with x & y here...
    funcOne(&x, y);
    printf("After funcOne: x = %d\n", one);
    
    z = 'B';
    printf("Before nextChar z = %c\n", z);
    //nextChar with z here...
    nextChar(&ch);
    printf("After nextChar: z = %c\n", ch);
    
    return 0;
}
void initialize(int* one, int* two, char* ch){
    one = 0;
    two = 0;
    if (ch) *ch = '~'; //<======= FIX HERE
}
void getHoursRate(double* rate, double* hours){
    printf("Enter hours worked: ");
    scanf("%lf", hours);
    printf("Enter pay rate: ");
    scanf("%lf", rate);
    
}
double payCheck(double rate, double hours){
    double amount = 0;
    
    if (hours > 40){
        amount += 40 * rate;
        amount += (hours - 40) * rate * 1.5;
        return amount;
    }
    else{
        amount += 40 * rate;
        return amount;
    }
}
void printCheck(double rate, double hours, double amount){
    printf("Hours worked: %lf\nPay Rate: %lf\nThis week's salary: %lf\n", hours, rate, amount);
}
void funcOne(int* pOne, int pTwo){
    int temp;
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d", &temp);
    if (pOne) *pOne = (*pOne * 2) + pTwo - temp;
}
void nextChar(char* ch){
    ch++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You never actually allocate memory for `one` and `two` so they have space to hold integer data, they're just null pointers. If your declare them as `int` so there's memory for the value (and use them accordingly), you should be halfway there.